# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Primitive' and 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm converting a project (not originally mine) from `python2` to `python3`.
In one of the scripts I've:

```
sk = (key.Sub[0]/["point", ["_CM"]]).value
```

This works on `py2`, **but not on** `py3`, which throws an error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Primitive' and 'list'
```

Apart from the error, I'm also confused about the original syntax `obj/list`.
Can you guys throw a light here?

Comment: This normally only works, given your `Primitive` class has a `__div__` method that has support for dividing with lists.

Comment: But why does it work on `py2` and not on `py3`, did the syntax change for this kind of operations?

Comment: The `/` operator behaves differently between Python 2 and 3; that may be the issue.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 What behavior changed in `/` from `py2` to `py3`? Do you mind to develop that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the different behavior of the division operator between Python 2 and 3.

```
PS C:\Users\TigerhawkT3> py -2
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class A:
...     def __div__(self, other):
...             return 'call div'
...     def __truediv__(self, other):
...             return 'call truediv'
...     def __floordiv__(self, other):
...             return 'call floordiv'
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a/3
'call div'
>>> a//3
'call floordiv'
>>> exit()
PS C:\Users\TigerhawkT3> py
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class A:
...     def __div__(self, other):
...             return 'call div'
...     def __truediv__(self, other):
...             return 'call truediv'
...     def __floordiv__(self, other):
...             return 'call floordiv'
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a/3
'call truediv'
>>> a//3
'call floordiv'
```

You'll need to define the `__truediv__` special method, rather than `__div__`, for Python 3. See the data models for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) for more info.

Comment: Your example helped me solving the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that `Primitive` implements `__div__` allowing it to be “divided” by another object (a list in this case). In Python 2 the operation `x / y` will use `x.__div__(y)` if it exists (and if it does not, then `y.__rdiv__(x)`.

In Python 3 this behaviour has **changed**.  To implement the `/` division operator you need to implement `__truediv__`.  This explains the difference you are observing.

Presumably you have access to the source for `Primitive`. Simply patch its `__div__` method to be `__truediv__`